# Scraping Date of News

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, google-news, python-newspaper

I am trying to do scraping from `https://finansial.bisnis.com/read/20210506/90/1391096/laba-bank-mega-tumbuh-dua-digit-kuartal-i-2021-ini-penopangnya`. I am trying to scrape the date of news, here's my code:

```
news['tanggal'] = newsScrape['date']
dates = []
for x in news['tanggal']:
    x = listToString(x)
    x = x.strip()
    x = x.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' \xa0|\xa0', ',').replace('|', ', ')
    dates.append(x)
dates = listToString(dates)
dates = dates[0:20]
if len(dates) == 0:
    continue
news['tanggal'] = dt.datetime.strptime(dates, '%d %B %Y, %H:%M')
```

but I got this error:

```
ValueError: time data '06 Mei 2021, 11:32  ' does not match format '%d %B %Y, %H:%M'
```

My assumption is because `Mei` is in Indonesian language, meanwhile the format need `May` which is in English. How to change `Mei` to be `May`? I have tried `dates = dates.replace('Mei', 'May')` but it doesnt work on me. When I tried it, I got error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:`   The type of dates is `string`. Thanks

Comment: What is the error when you tried `dates = dates.replace('Mei', 'May')`. Also, what's the type for `dates`?

Comment: @Daren I have edited in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following

```
import datetime as dt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url="https://finansial.bisnis.com/read/20210506/90/1391096/laba-bank-mega-tumbuh-dua-digit-kuartal-i-2021-ini-penopangnya"
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
info_soup= soup.find(class_="new-description")
x=info_soup.find('span').get_text(strip=True)
x = x.strip()
x = x.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' \xa0|\xa0', ',').replace('|', ', ')
x = x[0:20]
x = x.rstrip()
date= dt.datetime.strptime(x.replace('Mei', 'May'), '%d %B %Y, %H:%M')
print(date)
```

result:

```
2021-05-06 11:45:00
```

Comment: is there any other way if I want to change the other month? since it needs effort to replace 12 months

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption regarding the May -> Mei change is correct, the reason you're likely facing a problem after the replacement are the trailing spaces in your string, which are not accounted for in your format. You can use `string.rstrip()` to remove these spaces.

```py
import datetime as dt

dates = "06 Mei 2021, 11:32  "
dates = dates.replace("Mei", "May") # The replacement will have to be handled for all months, this is only an example
dates = dates.rstrip()
date = dt.datetime.strptime(dates, "%d %B %Y, %H:%M")
print(date) # 2021-05-06 11:32:00
```

While
this does fix the problem here, it's messy to have to shorten the string like this after `dates = dates[0:20]`. Consider using regex to gain the appropriate format at once.

Comment: is there any other way if I want to change the other month? since it needs effort to replace 12 months

Comment: You could use some sort of translation but that would be heavily overdoing it. First, you can write a dictionary of the form {"Mei": "May", ...}. If you know the month will always be in this language, you can pick the month off as month = dates.split()[1] and use this to get the pair from the dictionary and perform the replacement i.e. dates.replace(month, translations[month]). If not, you can simply loop through the dictionary and apply replace(key, value) for each pair.
Any way you choose a hard-coded translation is required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be just the trailing white space you have, which explains the error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:`  . It is complaining that it is unable to convert the remaining data (whitespace).

```
s = '06 Mei 2021, 11:32  '.replace('Mei', 'May').strip()
datetime.strptime(s, '%d %B %Y, %H:%M')
# Returns datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 6, 11, 32)
```

Also, to convert all the Indonesian months to English, you can use a dictionary:

```
id_en_dict = {
    ...,
    'Mei': 'May',
    ...
}
```

Comment: is there any other way if I want to change the other month? since it needs effort to replace 12 months